# Inline block in a flexbox in the column direction

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

How do I make C, D, E which have a `display: inline-block` occupy only as much space as they need to fit the text inside of them and can appear next to each another (side by side in a row) in a flexbox which has a `flex-direction` set to `column`? Please note that I do not want to wrap C, D, E in a container to get the desired result

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.a,.b,.c,.d,.e {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.c,.d,.e {
  display: inline-block;
}

.a {
  background: cyan;
}

.b {
  background: yellow;
}

.c {
  background: orange;
}

.d {
  background: gray;
}

.e {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate it further? Do you mean c d e is in one block?

Comment: try `align-self: center` for c,d and e instead of `inline-block`? Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Children of a flex container are **flex items** (its pseudos too). That's a synonym for *very special* :) `inline-block` has no effect on them, apart from [solving a flexbug with IE10](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#12-inline-elements-are-not-treated-as-flex-items). Only absolute positioning and `display: none` have an effect and a bunch of [flex properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (wrap, grow/shrink/basis for a width, on the main axis and cross axis, space between lines when wrapping, etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best way to go about this is to say which lines you want to take up 100% (in width) and then have everything else just take up one line.

You'll notice I've added `flex-wrap: wrap;` so a new line gets started when needed.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a,.b,.c,.d,.e {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.a {
  background: cyan;
}

.b {
  background: yellow;
}

.c {
  background: orange;
}

.d {
  background: gray;
}

.e {
  background: pink;
}

.a,.b {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** My answer is very different from the ones above, did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: No, you understood the question. The other answer did not. Quote from OP: *How do I make C, D, E ... appear next to each another*. This answer was very helpful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

You can do that using `flexbox` properties itslef - instead of `inline-block` use `align-self: center` (or `flex-start` as you see fit)

```
.c,.d,.e {
  align-self: center;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.a,.b,.c,.d,.e {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.c,.d,.e {
  align-self: center;
}

.a {
  background: cyan;
}

.b {
  background: yellow;
}

.c {
  background: orange;
}

.d {
  background: gray;
}

.e {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the `align-self`,  you save my day!